# Send attachments with MailKIt which comes from a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailkit

I´m using asp.net with c#

I send emails with MailKit including pdf attachments.
These pdf files are at the moment on my local computer.
This works so far without any problems.
For the local files I specify the path like this.

```
builder.Attachments.Add(@"C:\files\06\attachment.pdf");
```

Now I have the problem that the pdf attachments have to be loaded directly from a website.

i.e.:  https://website.com/files/06/atachment.pdf

Is this possible with Mailkit?
How do I specify the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this namespace

```
using System.Net;
```

Download your files to a path using `WebClient` class

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile (
        // Param1 = Link of file
        new System.Uri("https://website.com/files/06/atachment.pdf"),
        // Param2 = Path to save
        @"D:\Images\atachment.pdf"
    );
}
```

and then attach as usual

```
builder.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Images\atachment.pdf");
```

Comment: Great, that´s the solution.